# SecurityConfig for two Roles

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to use Spring Security, all worked with one role.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.formLogin().loginPage("/login");
    http.csrf().disable();

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/index","/","/ajouterFiliere").hasRole("RM");
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/index","/","/ajouterFiliere").hasRole("RF");

    http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");

}
```

its works for one role not for two role
please help me and thank you

Comment: Ofcourse this won't work. Just add the allowed roles to the `hasRole` instead of adding multiple lines. Only the first will match (as that matches the URL).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:
`http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/index","/","/ajouterFiliere").hasAnyRole("RM", "RF")`.

That should help.